# Subaru outback 2.5l 201

Tags: subaru, overheating, outback

My Subaru outback as engine problems. Engine light comes on the vehicle over heats. I have replaced the engine on the vehicle 2x. Both times the engine over heated. This is a 2011 outback 2.5L engine. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem? New thermostat was installed.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You don't give much detail as to what it's doing, other than overheating. Did you use a new or used engine as a replacement? Did you clean the radiator before first start up? Did you use new water pump or did you just throw it all back together?

Comment: What does "blowing the engine" mean?

Comment: It means that the engine  becomes damaged

Comment: Please describe the damage; "over heats" is very imprecise. What part(s) is (are) damaged? What kind of injury?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Read the OBDII codes related to the check engine light and report back to this forum.

In the meantime:

With the engine warmed up and running in Park, feel around the surface of the radiator.  If some spots are distinctly cooler than the others, the radiator has a blockage and needs replacement.

Is the coolant level dropping and you have to keep adding coolant, or smell coolant when you open the hood, you have a leak.  Look for stains around the center of the water pump or liquid coolant dripping from somewhere under the hood.  If you can't see anything, have the cooling system pressure tested by a mechanic.

Does the dashboard temp. indicator climb a little above normal, then drop back to normal?  If so, replace the thermostat.

Does the whole hood of the car become extremely hot, especially when stuck in traffic or after parking the car?  If so, replace the radiator fan.

Check for a blown head gasket.  Use this [test kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RS3N98V).